# How can getSharedPreferences(), an abstract method, has a body that allows it to retrieve information?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio so upon encountering the abstract method `getSharedPreferences()`.

I started to doubt whether what I know about abstract methods are true. So basically.
I read the information posted on the Android Developer site and I found that `getSharedPreferences()` is defined as an abstract methods which means that it doesn't have a body.

So how can this be called in the manner such as:

```
SharedPreferences test = getSharedPreferences("test",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Since `getSharedPreferences()` is abstract how can it serves the function of receiving the SharedPreferences when itself doesn't has any body to define what it must do?

Comment: abstract <> interface, abstract things can have a body

Comment: I appreciates your answer but can you go into a little details of give me an example because what you are saying to me is vague.

Comment: Well, I was wrong. Abstract methods ain't got no method bodies in java. See http://www.hitmaroc.xyz/2738675-5058-abstract-methods-inside-sharedpreferences.html

Comment: Actually I understand it now Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's abstract on the Context class, but there are many classes that implement Context. At least one is providing a method body for getSharedPreferences().

Comment: hey thanks for responding but if one is responsible for giving the method body for getSharedPreferences() then shouldn't there be a reference to that class when calling the method? for instance if  A extends Context and declares a method body for getSharedPreferences than shouldn't the method be called as    A.getSharedPreferences()?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you need to reference some method on the specific implementation of Context, then you can cast it to that type. So for example let's say the implementation of Context is an Activity, you can cast your Context variable to an Activity by doing this: Activity activity = (Activity)myContext. But be careful! You should always check to see if it's an instance of the class you are about to cast it to like this: if(myContext instanceof Activity) {Activity activity = (Activity)myContext}